# Tomar distintos datos de una consulta con AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Compañeros, estoy realizando un módulo de una página web en la cual, se muestran unos programas de educación y con esos programas, se muestran los productos que pertenecen a ese programa; para hacerlo más fácil, los divido en grupos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var consulta;
  //comprobamos si se pulsa una tecla
  $("#muestra_categoria").keyup(function(e) {
    //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo de búsqueda
    consulta = $("#buscar_categoria").serialize();
    alert(consulta); //Mostramos los datos del formulario.
    if (consulta != "") { //Si el formulario no está vacío, se enviarán los datos.
      //hace la búsqueda   
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "categorias.php",
        data: "categorias=" + consulta,
        dataType: "html",
        error: function() {
          alert("error petición ajax");
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#resultado").empty();
          $("#resultado").append(data);
        }
      });
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details id="prog">
  <summary>
    Gastronomía.
  </summary>
  <form method="POST" id="buscar_categoria">
    <input type="text" id="muestra_categoria" name="muestra_categoria">
    <input type='number' name='id_programa' value=1>
  </form>
</details>
<details id="prog">
  <summary>
    Panadería.
  </summary>
  <form method="POST" id="buscar_categoria">
    <input type="text" id="muestra_categoria" name="muestra_categoria">
    <input type='number' name='id_programa' value=2>
  </form>
</details>
```

Como se ve en el ejemplo, me toma sólo el formulario del primer programa (que en este caso, es Gastronomía, que en la Base de datos, tiene id_prog=1).

**Lo que quiero, es saber cómo hacer que me tome todos los demás programas y me los diferencie para así buscar las categorías pertenecientes a cada programa y que además me llame la consulta.**

Este es el código (.php) real:

```
<?php
$programas=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM programas");
while ($p=mysqli_fetch_array($programas)) {
    echo "<details id='programa'>";
    echo "<summary>";
    echo $p['nombre_prog'];
    echo "</summary>";
    ?>
    <form method="POST" id="buscar_categoria">
    <input type="text" id="muestra_categoria" name="muestra_categoria">
    <?php
    echo "<input type='number' name='id_programa' value='" . $p['id_prog'] . "'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<section id='resultado'></section>";
    echo "</details>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, recuerda que los los atributos ID son únicos, tu los estas repitiendo por cada programa. Si quieres ejecutar una misma acción en cada uno de ellos, mejor utiliza clases:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var consulta;
  //comprobamos si se pulsa una tecla
  $(".muestra_categoria").keyup(function(e) {
//Este es tu tag details que encierra cada formulario
var contenedor_padre = $(this).closest('.prog');
//Este es el tag section que contendrá el resultado
var section_resutado = contenedor_padre.find('.resultado');
//obtengo el formulario
var formulario =  contenedor_padre.find(".buscar_categoria");
//método mas abajo...
if(esValido(formulario)){
  //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo de búsqueda
  var consulta = formulario.serialize();

  alert(consulta); //Mostramos los datos del formulario. 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "categorias.php",
    data: "categorias=" + consulta,
    dataType: "html",
    error: function() {
      section_resutado.text("error petición ajax");
    },
    success: function(data) {
      section_resutado.empty();
      section_resutado.append(data);
    }
  });
}
else{
  section_resutado.empty();
}
  });
});

function esValido(formulario){
  //reconocer cantidad de errores
  errores = 0;
  //obtengo los campos del formulario
  var inputs = formulario.find('input');
  //recorro los campos del formulario
  inputs.each(function(index, input){
//si el campo esta vacio, incremento la variable de errores
if(input.value.trim() === ""){
   errores++;
 }
  });
  //si errores es mayor que 0, retorno false (el formulario no es valido)
  //En caso contrario retorno true (el formulario es valido)
  return (errores>0)?false:true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details class="prog">
  <summary>
    Gastronomía.
  </summary>
  <form method="POST" class="buscar_categoria">
    <input type="text" class="muestra_categoria" name="muestra_categoria">
    <input type='number' name='id_programa' value=1>
  </form>
  <section class='resultado'></section>
</details>
<details class="prog">
  <summary>
    Panadería.
  </summary>
  <form method="POST" class="buscar_categoria">
    <input type="text" class="muestra_categoria" name="muestra_categoria">
    <input type='number' name='id_programa' value=2>
  </form>
  <section class='resultado'></section>
</details>
```

Lo de "que además me llame la consulta." no lo entendí, disculpa.

Comment: O sea, ¿Cambio todos los ID, por CLASS? La parte de la consulta, es que me muestre la consulta que se realiza con los datos que se van a llevar a otra página dentro de la sección (<section id='resultado'></section>), pero quisiera saber si en esa sección también le pongo una clase.

Comment: Si. Pero también modifiqué un poco el JS, te deje unos comentarios. Pon ejecutar para que veas el ejemplo :D.

Comment: Listo. Ya lo probé. Calificaré tu respuesta como correcta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Gracias! Cualquier cosa me comentas.

Comment: De hecho, quisiera pedirte otro favor, aunque es más pequeño.

Comment: Si obvio, dime.

Comment: ¿Cómo sería el JavaScript para que cuanto la variable consulta esté vacía no me muestre ningún resultado, sólo la barra de búsqueda'

Comment: Actualice el JS, es lo que quieres que pase? una manera sencilla es esa. Aunque hay mas complejas. Me comentas!

Comment: Oye, he vuelto. Quisiera saber cómo evitar que mi página principal me realice el JS una sola vez. Es que cuando llamo el .php a la página principal, esta me genera la consulta varias veces y eso mismo hace que el llamado a las categorías me sea extremadamente lento.